# What shape input and outputs are expected for sklearn pairwise_distance functions?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have two vectors of shape (2400,)

I combine them like this:

```
vecs = [matrix1, matrix2]
combined_matricies = np.array(vecs)
print("Combined shape:", combined_matricies.shape)
```

> Combined shape: (2, 2400)

Then I run

```
distance_mat = pairwise_distances(combined_matricies, metric="cosine").astype('float64')
print(distance_mat.shape)
```

> (2, 2)

Why isn't this (2, 2400)?

Comment: Why would you expect `(2, 2400)` shaped output? Its doing for all elems in mat1 against all in `mat2` and not against the corresponding ones (if you are mistaking on it).

Comment: @VivekKumar I didn't understand their terminology for what "sample" refers to! Thanks.

Comment: As I said in previous comment, one sample means one row. For machine learning, one sample means one independent set of observations which belong to one class (for classification task) or to one cluster (for clustering). In short one sample can have many features which enables the algorithm to process it. Samples are represented in rows and features in columns for scikit-learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you the cosine between two vectors of size 2,400.

So essentially `distance_mat[0, 0]` and `distance_mat[1, 1]` are zeros and both `distance_mat[1, 0]` and `distance_mat[0, 1]` are the cosine between the two vectors of size 1 x 2,400.

If you want element-wise product use:

```
np.multiply(matrix1, matrix2)
```